# c++ fix wrong string in library at runtime

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I come across a problem where a function of a shared library I tried to use was using a incorrect constant string for internal calculation. The string is later passed to a system call.
Now I'm wondering if it would have been possible to "patch" that library in memory without modifying it on disk or duplicating functionality. The correct string for that library would also have been shorter, so allocating memory is not a problem.
The string was "/bin/bash" and should have been "/bin/sh" within a Windows library called "wslapi.dll" (the one responsible for windows subsystem for linux).
The bug is fixed in later versions of windows 10, but as saied earlier, I just got curious how someone could "hack around that bug" and how that technique is called.

Comment: Since constants are will usually be stored in a read-only section of your DLL, I doubt this would be easy to accomplish, if possible at all.

Comment: @andreee How was that memory written to if it is read-only?

Comment: That's what you said: _"[...] was using a incorrect **constant** string for internal calculation"_. So that memory cannot be written.

Comment: @KillzoneKid the operating system maps it and marks it as read-only.

Comment: @spectras You can fix that with [VirtualProtectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366899(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @PaulSanders that would only work if the system has not mapped DLL read-only section as a read-only view of the file. I guess the only way to tell is to actually try.

Comment: @spectras but loading dlls could also be don by the calling application, so it could be mapped read write, or couldn't it? As my application is calling it it sounds possible but unfeasible for me by today.

Comment: @K.Frank though technically possible, loading a dynamic object is no simple endeavor, you would need to re-implement the whole dynamic linking functionality in your program: loading PE files, resolving symbols, performing relocation, running init sections and so on. I don't see why you would want to do this.

Comment: (if you are interested in an outline of the process, [this page](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/08/what-happens-when-you-load-a-library/) does a pretty good job).